# How to find non-audible ("subliminal") messages by using Audacity?

Tags: subconscious

I bought a programme which consists of a set of mp3 files.
The authors claim they put subliminal messages (i.e. messages at non-audible frequency but received by the brain) in these mp3s which make you better in various area of you life (e.g. relationships, business etc) through non-audible motivational messages.

Now, I'm trying to see if this is true.
They claim these messages are not audible because out of human hearing spectrum.
I also asked some clarification and they state subliminal messages have been inserted both at low and high frequencies (but in all cases out of human hearing spectrum).

What I've already done is:

- normalize the audio (already did)
- decrease speed by 25%-50% (already did)
- reversing the audio track (already did, but **I'm not sure whether these subliminal messages are supposed to be encoded using backmasking or not**)

What I want to do is:

- totally **remove all the audible frequencies** (in order to remove the music and the messages that are actually audible)
- **make the remaning spectrum audible** (here I have no idea on how to do it. But if they encoded these messages, then I guess it's possible to bring the messages back to an audible frequency

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: Sure it's xmas, not 1st April? - outside hearing spectrum = either didn't encode in the first place… or you can't hear them. I'm coining a new term… "audiopathy".

Comment: haha, not yet Christmas but I did a similar reasoning

Comment: I would put it firmly in the camp the Americans would call 'snake oil' - along with homeopathy & a lot of the 'oxygenated copper' type audiophile delusions ;-)

Comment: This is not a real question. Don't listen to snake oil peddlers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So they put in 'messages' at frequencies which the sound files they use cannot contain and conventional speakers cannot reproduce...

Don't waste your time.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting topic, but there seems to be some stuff missing or is just unclear. Mp3 files are compressed a lot and also automatically cut off frequencies that are non-audible. So I am not sure if there will be any there unless there is a flac or wav version also available.

Comment: I had the some thought, indeed. The compression has the mp3's best quality (320Kbps). Now, I want to see if there are or there are not these non-audible frequencies they're advertising

Comment: Do you have Izotope?

Comment: no. I didn't even know it exists. I had a look to their website but they have many softwares (and they don't look for beginners at all)

Comment: Yeah, I doubt there would be any non-audible frequencies because it is mp3.

Answer (score 3):

This simply doesn't work.  Period.  The reason you don't hear certain sounds is not that your brain just doesn't process them as sound, it is that your ear's can't physically detect the sound.  There is literally no way for your body to be aware of their existence.  In the case of low frequencies you arguably might be able to feel them, but they still wouldn't be interpreted by the brain as any kind of message.

Additionally, speakers are only designed to play back sound in the human hearing range, so you wouldn't be able to play back the sounds even if your brain could somehow get the information.  MP3s aren't designed to relay information that can't be heard either.  Even uncompressed WAV or CD audio isn't designed to hold frequencies above the human hearing limit.

So even without bothering to check for it, there is no way the claims have any merit at all.